# If $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, and $f$ is twice-differentiable then $f''(u)=0$ for some $u$ in $(0,2)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let the real-valued function $f$ be continuous on $[0,2]$ and twice-differentiable on $(0,2)$. Assume that $f(0)=0$, that $f(1)=1$, and $f(2)=2$.

Prove that there exists $u\in(0,2)$ such that $f''(u)=0$.

Comment: I couldn't even start...

Comment: How comes you "couldn't even start"? Which similar results can you prove?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**hint**

Let $g (x)=f (x)-x $

then
$$g (0)=g (1)=g (2)=0$$

Apply Rolle's Theorem at $[0,1] $ and $[1,2] $ to get $c_1$ and $c_2$.
then apply it again to the derivative $g'$ at $[c_1,c_2] $.

observe that $$g''(x)=f''(x). $$

Answer (score 2):

By mean value theorem:

$f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, so there exists an $s \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(s) = 1$.

$f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 2$, so there exists a $t \in (1, 2)$ such that $f'(t) = 1$.

$f'(s) = f'(t) = 1$, so there exists an $u \in (s, t)\subset (0,2)$ such that $f''(u) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What does the mean value theorem tell you? Consider separately the intervals $(0,1)$ and $ (1,2)$. See what you can do from there (maybe Rolle's might be helpful).